# Measuring Memory Bandwidth Utilization in Linux

Tags: linux, performance, memory, perf

How can I use perf to measure the hardware performance events UNC_QMC_NORMAL_READS and UNC_QMC_WRITES caused by a specific process in Linux?

Comment: What is your CPU model? First check these events are supported by it and then look at "raw events" in the perf doc and code, to understand their format for your target.

Comment: Try ocperf script from Intel: https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/blob/master/ocperf.py